# What pattern to use to create locks on SQLAlchemy models for a flask webapp?

Tags: python, flask, redis, sqlalchemy, locking

I have several models that should really only be edited by one person at a time. Using the info from [this repository](https://github.com/SPSCommerce/redlock-py/blob/master/README.md), it looks like creates a named lock "object".

```
dlm = Redlock([{"host": "localhost", "port": 6379, "db": 0}, ])

my_lock = dlm.lock("my_resource_name",1000)

...

dlm.unlock(my_lock)
```

But in my webapp how would I keep track of those lock objects? I had hoped to create a unique string out of `userid_modelname_modelid` and create named lock with default ttl of ~20 minutes. When the user submits a db update (or cancels out of the modifications) the string name would then be recreated and used to unlock the model.

Routes that involve checking out of models would have a decorated function that performed that functionality

```
@modelcheckout(current_user, 'region', regionid)
@myblueprint.route('/editregion/<regionid>', methods=['GET', 'POST])
...
```

*** no `Flask-SQLAlchemy`